# How to make lxml output file with utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, lxml

**data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArticleSet>
    <Article>            
        <LastName>Bojarski</LastName>
        <ForeName>-</ForeName>
        <Affiliation>-</Affiliation>            
    </Article>
    <Article>            
        <LastName>Genç</LastName>
        <ForeName>Yasemin</ForeName>
        <Affiliation>fgjfgnfgn</Affiliation>            
    </Article>
</ArticleSet>
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
from lxml import etree

dom = etree.parse('data.xml')
root = dom.getroot()

for article in dom.xpath('Article[Affiliation="-"]'):
    root.remove(article)

dom.write('output.xml')
```

This code deletes articles whose Affiliation is equal to - i.e. whose affiliation tag looks like `<Affliation>-</Affliation>`
when I store the remaining output into output.xml it parses the Unicode character `Genç` to `Gen&#231;` I want to store it as it is.

**Code's output**

```
<ArticleSet>
    <Article>            
        <LastName>Gen&#231;</LastName>
        <ForeName>Yasemin</ForeName>
        <Affiliation>fgjfgnfgn</Affiliation>            
    </Article>
</ArticleSet>
```

**Required output**

```
<ArticleSet>
    <Article>            
        <LastName>Genç</LastName>
        <ForeName>Yasemin</ForeName>
        <Affiliation>fgjfgnfgn</Affiliation>            
    </Article>
</ArticleSet>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the `encoding` parameter in the `etree.write` method. You may also use `xml_declaration=True` to declare encoding of the output document.

```
dom.write('output.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

See [lxml documentation](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write).

Comment: Wow I tried some stuff and this made sense and it actually worked out fine at first try. I got my åäö, thanks!